# Modify default JSON error response from Spring Boot Rest Controller

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-boot

Currently the error response from spring boot contains the standard content like below:

```
{
   "timestamp" : 1426615606,
   "exception" : "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
   "status" : 400,
   "error" : "Bad Request",
   "path" : "/welcome",
   "message" : "Required String parameter 'name' is not present"
}
```

I am looking for a way to get rid of the "exception" property in the response. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As described in the [documentation on error handling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling), you can provide your own bean that implements `ErrorAttributes` to take control of the content.

An easy way to do that is to subclass `DefaultErrorAttributes`. For example:

```
@Bean
public ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
    return new DefaultErrorAttributes() {
        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(RequestAttributes requestAttributes, boolean includeStackTrace) {
            Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
            // Customize the default entries in errorAttributes to suit your needs
            return errorAttributes;
        }

   };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried to use the ErrorAttributes but i seem to be unable to get this unit tested. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120948/unit-testing-a-spring-boot-application-with-custom-errorattributes] Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: How do you determine parent class?

Comment: @MatejJ Sorry, I’m not sure that I understand what you’re asking. What do you mean by “determine parent class”?

Comment: You mentioned you need to subclass `DefaultErrorAttributes`. I am not sure where spring boot calls `super.getErrorAttributes`

Answer (score 42):

If there is empty message text in json when you encounter exception, you can be hit by [changed behavior in spring boot 2.3.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content). If this is the case, just change your `server.error.include-message` property to `always`.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes
Changes to the Default Error Page’s Content
The error message and any binding errors are no longer included in the default error page by default. This reduces the risk of leaking information to a client. `server.error.include-message` and `server.error.include-binding-errors` can be used to control the inclusion of the message and binding errors respectively. Supported values are `always, on-param, and never`. Use `always` will fix the empty message from spring boot 2.3.0 release

Answer (score 7):

Following answer is totally derived from [Andy Wilkinson's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106637/modify-default-json-error-response-from-spring-boot-rest-controller#29109756) answer *(which uses `web.reactive` classes)*
- It includes `web.servlet` based classes.
- Spring boot 2.2.4.RELEASE

> **`ExceptionHandlerConfig.java`**

```
package com.example.sample.core.exception;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.DefaultErrorAttributes;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorAttributes;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

@Configuration
public class ExceptionHandlerConfig {

    //private static final String DEFAULT_KEY_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    private static final String DEFAULT_KEY_STATUS = "status";
    private static final String DEFAULT_KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static final String DEFAULT_KEY_ERRORS = "errors";
    private static final String DEFAULT_KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
    //private static final String DEFAULT_KEY_PATH = "path";

    public static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String KEY_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    public static final String KEY_ERRORS = "errors";

    //

    @Bean
    public ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
        return new DefaultErrorAttributes() {

            @Override
            public Map<String ,Object> getErrorAttributes(
                WebRequest webRequest
                ,boolean includeStackTrace
            ) {
                Map<String ,Object> defaultMap
                    = super.getErrorAttributes( webRequest ,includeStackTrace );

                Map<String ,Object> errorAttributes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                // Customize.
                // For eg: Only add the keys you want.
                errorAttributes.put( KEY_STATUS, defaultMap.get( DEFAULT_KEY_STATUS ) );                    
                errorAttributes.put( KEY_MESSAGE ,defaultMap.get( DEFAULT_KEY_MESSAGE ) );

                return errorAttributes;
            }
        };
    }
}
```