# Testing a Spring Boot application with custom ErrorAttributes?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to test a Spring Boot RestController that should use custom error attributes.

```
    @Bean
public ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
    return new DefaultErrorAttributes() {

        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(
                RequestAttributes requestAttributes,
                boolean includeStackTrace) {
            Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
            Throwable error = getError(requestAttributes);
            return errorAttributes;
        }

    };
}
```

But when i try to test the custom error attributes using a simple test these properties are not taken into account. The test below actually fires a request and i except that the custom attributes are used. But whatever i seem to do the code seems to be not taken into account.

```
class TestSpec extends Specification {

    MockMvc mockMvc

    def setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new HelloWorldController()).build()
    }

    def "Test simple action"() {
        when:
        def response = mockMvc.perform(post("/hello")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content('{"sayHelloTo": ""}')
        )

        then:
        response.andExpect(status().isOk())
    }
}
```

Any clue on how i could test if the custom attributes?

Answer (score 12):

Spring Boot's error infrastructure works by forwarding requests to an error controller. It's this error controller that uses an `ErrorAttributes` instance. MockMvc only had fairly basic support for testing the forwarding of requests (you can check that the request would be forwarded, but not the actual outcome of that forward). This means that a MockMvc test that calls your `HellowWorldController`, either using standalone setup or a web application context-based setup, isn't going to drive the right code path.

A few options:

- Unit test your custom `ErrorAttributes` class directly
- Write a MockMvc-based test that calls Spring Boot's `BasicErrorController` configured with your custom `ErrorAttributes` instance
- Write an integration test that uses `RestTemplate` to make an actual HTTP call into your service

Comment: Do you have an example how to achieve the second approach? I can't get my head around that.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the reply. I can't even check properly if the request was forwarded. When I debugged it, I saw that `forwardedUrl` of `MockHttpServletResponse` is null but shouldn't it be forwarded to `/error`? Is there any necessary configuration to apply this forward in `MockMvc`?

Answer (score 3):

The [test class from Spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/error/DefaultErrorAttributesTests.java) gives you a good place to start your own tests!

Create an instance of your custom error attributes class and use MockHttpServletRequest and WebRequest:

```
private final DefaultErrorAttributes errorAttributes = new YourCustomErrorAttributes();
private final MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
private final WebRequest webRequest = new ServletWebRequest(this.request);
```

For your test method:

```
//Set the appropriate error state in your mocked request object:
RuntimeException ex = new RuntimeException("Test");
this.request.setAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception", ex);

//Pass the mocked request into the the methods that are normally called by the framework 
Map<String, Object> attributes = this.errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(this.webRequest, ErrorAttributeOptions.of(Include.STACK_TRACE));   

// add your own asserts
assertThat(attributes.get("trace").toString()).startsWith("java.lang");
```