# Can you change the 401 error response?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

My question is, can you change the structure of the response of the 401 error message?

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken"
}
```

for example

```
{
    "timestamp" : 123124354,
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "The username or password are not valid!"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered a while ago: [Modify default JSON error response from Spring Boot Rest Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106637/modify-default-json-error-response-from-spring-boot-rest-controller). Checking the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling) I would recommend going with the `@ControllerAdvice` to give you the most flexibility on defining how the JSON response is returned.