# Which model class does spring use for error responses of Request Mapping methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, response

I am designing a POJO for custom error scenarios of my `@RequestMapping` methods.

Spring by default throws a `HttpMessageNotReadableException` if a `POST` is made without any body and returns the error response very nicely as something like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2017-07-28T18:54:11.867+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message": "Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<some.package.name.SomeResponseClass> some.package.name.SomeControllerClass.someRequestMappingMethod(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>, some.package.name.SomeRequestClass)",
    "path": "/somepath/"
}
```

Similarly if validation for any field annotated with `@Valid` fails, it throws `MethodArgumentNotValidException` and returns the error response as:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2017-07-28T17:23:53.102+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "NotNull.incident.someField",
                "NotNull.someField",
                "NotNull.java.lang.String",
                "NotNull"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "someObject.someField",
                        "someField"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "someField",
                    "code": "someField"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "someField is null",
            "objectName": "someObject",
            "field": "someField",
            "rejectedValue": null,
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "NotNull"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Validation failed for object='someObject'. Error count: 2",
    "path": "/somepath/"
}
```

I an having an understanding that in either of the above case Spring must be returning a `ResponseEntity` object with headers and body wrapped in it.
And there must be a model class representing the body having fields like above i.e. `timestamp`, `status`, `error` etc. I just wished to visit that class to get an idea of what all fields Spring has included in their error response model. Or may be I might want to extend it. I have spent quite a huge amount of time by now searching for that class, but couldn't find.

The best I could find is `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler#handleException()`, but my debugger will not even go at the break-point set there!!

Can anyone point me to the package where it exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE / Spring 4.3.7

It's a `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>`.

Found it by searching for ErrorController - There is a class `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController`

It's method `error` is called when an error occurres and it looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> error(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, Object> body = getErrorAttributes(request,
            isIncludeStackTrace(request, MediaType.ALL));
    HttpStatus status = getStatus(request);
    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(body, status);
}
```

You can dig in the mehod `getErrorAttributes` to find out how the Map is built.

Answer (score 1):

Following class will give you idea about how response is generated in case of error
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DefaultErrorAttributes

Reference:

[Modify default JSON error response from Spring Boot Rest Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106637/modify-default-json-error-response-from-spring-boot-rest-controller)

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling

Also if you want to customize response in case of error you can use following approach as well
@ControllerAdvice along with @ExceptionHandler

Another class to refer for error handling
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

Comment: This was helpful, Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the external links. However, both the answers here are equally helpful to me and I can accept only one. So I am accepting the one answered first. :)