# how to customize the ErrorHandler class with customized body contents for jetty server in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty

I have a spring boot application that run on jetty server. the requirement is to customize the 404 and other errors with our own messages. After searching for a while got to a point that we can do it by a custom class by extending the `ErrorHandler` class of jetty package and override the method `getErrorPage(HttpServletRequest request)`.

doubt: was not able to figure out how to configure this customized class in spring boot application to over ride the default ErrorHandler class. Is there a way to inject this custom class?

Any help/suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: If you are using Servlets, just make an error-page handler in your webapp. - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/how-to-specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398385/spring-boot-and-custom-404-error-page

Comment: If you just want to modify the content of the default JSON response returned by Spring Boot on _embedded_ Jetty, this would be the easiest way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106637/modify-default-json-error-response-from-spring-boot-rest-controller#29109756

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve this custom error handling by creating a custom class by extending the

```
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler
```

class( as mentioned in my question) and overriding the doError method.

this custom class needs to configured as an error handler class while initiating the jetty server as below.

```
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server server = new Server();
server.setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());
```

As a result when any wrong URL is sent to your application then your custom error handler class method will be called where you can write your own custom response body/content.