# Remove type and properties from ResponseStatusException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-3

I'm throwing the following response status exception in my Spring Boot 3.0 application.

```
throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "No ids have been provided");
```

This returns the following json error message. But, I don't need the `type` and `properties` attributes in this response. Is there away to remove them from the returned json object?

```
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "No ids have been provided",
    "instance": "/api/",
    "properties": null
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify default JSON error response from Spring Boot Rest Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106637/modify-default-json-error-response-from-spring-boot-rest-controller)